# Sorting a std::vector<std::pair<std::string,bool>> by the string?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector, std-pair

How can I sort this `vector` by comparing the `pair.first` which is an `std::string`? (without providing a static compare function, nor use boost).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, bool> > v;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

`std::pair` overloads `operator<` to sort first by the `first` element then by the `second` element.  Thus, if you just sort the `vector` using the default sort ordering (`operator<`), you'll get your desired ordering.

Comment: This is a C++0x only answer. ;)  Edit: Now fixed (`>>` token closing two nested template `<>` pairs is C++0x only).

Comment: @Charles: Ha!  Yeah, I probably do that in a lot of answers. I'm too used to using a compiler that supports `>>`.

Comment: +1: I didn't know that `std::pair::operator<()` was overloaded.  I do now!

Comment: Just to be picky, this requires that the second item in the pair has `<` defined. If the second type is not sortable then this will fail.

Comment: @edA:  Yes.  The OP's pair has a `bool` as its second element type, which is comparable.

Answer (score 4):

I really like James' answer, but there's one other option you might want to consider - just funnel everything into a `std::map`:

```
std::map<std::string, bool> myMap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Or, if you have duplicate strings, a `std::multimap`:

```
std::multimap<std::string, bool> myMultiMap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

This does have the added advantage that if you then need to add or remove new key/value pairs, you can do so in O(lg n), as opposed to O(n) for the sorted vector.

If you really must use a vector, then go with James' answer.  However, if you have a vector of pairs, there's a good chance that you really want a `std::map`.

Comment: I need to consider the case where the user does not want them sorted and in the order they gave them.

Comment: Also vector + sort may in practice be much faster than inserting lots of stuff into a (multi)map, regardless of what the big-O notation says.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to "duplicate question" of this:
link: [Sort a vector of pairs by first element then by second element of the pair in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18029110/9805897)

```
bool cmp(const pair<int,int>&x,const pair<int,int>y){
if(x.first==y.first){
   return(x.second<y.second);
}
return(x.first<y.first);
}

array of pairs before:
5 2
4 2
8 2
8 3
8 1
array of pairs after:
4 2
5 2
8 1
8 2
8 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom comparator to order on the pairs' `.first` only.

```
sort(begin, end,
     compose2(less<string>(),
              select1st<pair<string, bool> >(),
              select1st<pair<string, bool> >()));
```

Comment: Note that `select1st` is not part of the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Mmm.  Luckily, it's trivial to write: `template<class T> struct select1st : public unary_function<T, typename T::first_type> { const typename T::first_type& operator()(const T& x) const {return x.first;} };`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide any compare function since by default since the sort() function will sort vector in ascending order of values. As each element is a pair, so one pair will be smaller than other one if the first value of one pair is smaller than that for other pair.

```
vector<pair<string,int>>v;
v = {{"xyz",1},{"pq",2}};   // Sample input
sort(v.begin(),v.end());    // Requires #include<algorithm> header
```