# Sort a vector of pairs by first element then by second element of the pair in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

If I have a `vector<pair<int,int> >` datatype, what is the accepted way to sort it by the first element of the pair and then by second if the firsts are equal? For instance maybe (1,10), (3,3), (7,13), (7,16), (8,1), (8,2), (15,2) etc.

Comment: `std::sort` with custom comparator

Comment: Uh, dude, you want to sort by the second if the firsts are equal, and yet you said otherwise in your comment on my answer.

Comment: You originally commented on my question: *"any way to preserve order in the second?"* So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pair`s by default compare by first element, then second. So, if you don't care about preserving the order when the first elements compare equal, then you can just use `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: This is what I was already using but it doesn't seem to work as intended

Comment: In what way? The big caveat is that it will sort by second element if the first elements are equal (instead of preserving their original order).

Comment: @AgainstASicilian You might be looking for `std::stable_sort`?

Comment: @nneonneo I do care about preserving order though

Comment: @Rapptz stable_sort and sort would result in the same result for pair<int,int>'s.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Don't put all the important info in comments, include it in your original question.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: Seeing your revision, you clearly don't care about the original order of the second element because you want to sort them. So `std::sort` is **exactly** what you need. If it ain't working, that's a different problem.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Important info includes things like that you want a stable sort (and why ... it's not clear that you understand what a stable sort is), what you tried, what the result was and how it differed from what you want ...

Comment: @nneonneo Maybe my English is off, but by preserve order I meant make sure it is in order. I think that's the wrong way though and I am sorry! I will be clearer next time

Comment: @neonneo If, say, the second elements were already sorted, then one might want to do a stable sort on just the first elements.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: "preserve" means to keep as it originally was; you want "ensure".

Comment: @AgainstASicilian A stable sort preserves (keeps) *the original order* of equal elements. Putting things in order is just sorting them.

Comment: My mistake, sorry everyone. I mean that I want to sort by first and then sort by second when the firsts are equal

Comment: @AgainstASicilian As this answer says, std::sort does that. You said it doesn't seem to work as intended, but you have given no indication of what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::pair`s comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) compare pairs lexicographically, it first compares the first elements, then the second elements if the first elements are equal.

[Here is an example of using `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` and `std::sort`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=52055275990186df53bfb86fea09cc3a-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Using `std::sort` that way uses `std::pair`'s `operator <`, which, as said above, compares the pairs lexicographically.

**UPDATE:** [Here is an example using `std::stable_sort` and a custom comparison function that compares only the first element](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=94ff92482b797e8d7483e98d84d0b55b-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

By using [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), you are guaranteed that the relative order of equal elements are preserved. That is, even if the first elements of the `std::pairs` are equal, the original relative order is still retained.

Comment: any way to increase order in the second when the firsts are equal?