# How do i sort a pair increasing based on first element then decreasing based on second element?

Tags: c++

How do i sort  pair like this for example :

Input :

1 99

2 100

1 100

3 400

2 101

output :

1 100

1 99

2 101

2 100

3 400

Comment: Do you know about `if` statements and comparison operators (e.g. `<`, `>`, `<=', `>=`, etc.)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a vector of pairs by first element then by second element of the pair in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029110/sort-a-vector-of-pairs-by-first-element-then-by-second-element-of-the-pair-in-c)

Comment: @Drop Doesn't that sort ascending for `first` and `second`?

Comment: wait going paste it here

Comment: btw its not duplicate my question is different

Comment: @nff21 Yes, your question is significantly different. Unique and never been asked before. So using search is not even an option

Comment: do you even read my question properly ?

Comment: The answer is simple but we can't help you if you don't show us what you have tried. This community is not here to write code for you. Answer: sort on `first` by checking `<` and if `first` is equivalent then proceed to sort on `second` by checking `>`

Answer (score 2):

Create a comparator and use the `std::sort` function.

```
struct Comp {
  bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int> &a, const std::pair<int, int> &b) {
    if (a.first != b.first) {
      return a.first < b.first;
    }
    return a.second > b.second;
  }

};
```

Then create an instance of the struct and pass it into `std::sort`.

```
Comp comp_functor;
std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), comp_functor);
```

To do this you'd need to `#include <algorithm>`. Also note that `std::sort` does not guarantee stability so if you want stability use `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: You shouldn't be enabling users that ask bad questions (i.e., that are off-topic), see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), by answering them.

Comment: As written, if `b.first` is greater than `a.first` it starts comparing on `second` ...

Comment: I saw the comment chain above but decided to post anyway because I thought the user might benefit from learning about what a comparator is (I'm assuming he hasn't seen them before, otherwise this exercise would have been trivial for him). Although the way he worded his question wasn't good I still think he deserves a well thought out answer.