# c++ sorting a vector of pair with a self defined template library

Tags: c++, templates

**Solved**
Thanks, I used David Schwartz's answer and solved the problem. Below is the code that I can use.

The original question I have is how to sort a vector of pair, and I get the answer from here :
[Sorting a std::vector<std::pair<std::string,bool>> by the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610232/sorting-a-stdvectorstdpairstdstring-bool-by-the-string)

Then I want to keep this method in my library my_lib.hpp, so that I can use it when I needed and also, I want to try to make a template for it.
Following is my setting, and my problem is I get this error in eclipse

> undefined reference to `void  haha::pair_sort_second_dec<std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)`    main.cpp        /question       line 406        C/C++ Problem

**my_lib.hpp**

```
namespace haha{
template <class T>
bool pairCompare_dec(const T& , const T& );
template <class T>
void pair_sort_second_dec(std::vector<T>& );


template <class T>
bool pairCompare_dec(const T& firstElem,const T& secondElem) {
  return firstElem.second > secondElem.second;
}
template <class T>
void pair_sort_second_dec(std::vector<T>& target){
    std::sort(target.begin(),target.end(),pairCompare_dec<T>);
}
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "my_lib.hpp"

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string> > test;
    // initial test
    haha::pair_sort_second_dec(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "undefined reference to [function-name]" isn't precise text of the error, because there is nothing called `[function-name]` here. When asking about problems involving an error message, you have to quote the error message _exactly_.

Comment: And the error certainly indicates a location too. Include it and state what part of the shown code it corresponds to.

Comment: @JanHudec sorry, I have added the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::sort(target.begin(),target.end(),pairCompare_dec);
```

Should be:

```
std::sort(target.begin(),target.end(),pairCompare_dec<T>);
```