# Any alternative for pairs?

Tags: c++, c, functional-programming

I have many points (a,b) and I stored x coordinate in a[] and y coordinate in b[]. Now I need to sort these points wrt x-coordinate or y-coordinate. I know that there is concept of pairs in C++ but is there any better way of doing this. Please give answers in C/C++.

Comment: I can't imagine a better way of storing pairs of two integers then in a struct of pair of two integers.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++, or do you want something that works in both?

Comment: You can create a custom iterator for `a` such that when you `sort` it, it also modifies the order in `b` to remain consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the pair of coordinates using `std::pair<int, int>`, or as the answer by @Gopi indicates by a `struct`.

A collection of either of those can be sorted by the X coordinate or by the Y coordinate by using a lambda function, a functor, or a global function.

```
// A vector of vertices.
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vertices;

// Sort the vertices by X coordinates using a lambda function to order them
std::sort(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(),
         [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.first < b.first; });

// Sort the vertices by Y coordinates using a lambda function to order them
std::sort(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(),
          [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.second < b.second; });
```

Comment: `pair` already has a comparison function, it compares `first` and if they are equal it compares `second` so you don't need to pass a lambda to the first sort there.

Comment: @JonathanMee, true. If a user wants to sort them by just the X coordinate and ignore the Y coordinate, then the compare function is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct vertex
{
int x;
int y;
};
```

Then sort the structures accordingly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to sort the array of these structures using sort() function of C++

Comment: @user3901994 `std::sort(std::begin(an_array), std::end(an_array), [] (vertex const & a, vertex const & b) { return a.x < b.x; });` <-- replace `a.x < b.x` with `a.y < b.y` to sort by the `y` field instead of the `x` field.

Comment: @cdhowie I think it is instrumental to point out that your compartor utilizes lambda functions and needs the C++11 flag to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `struct` as pointed out and shown in other answers. However, if you define your own struct you will need to define a comparator function to use with the sorting algorithm or overload the `<` operator.

The advantage of using `std::pair` is that you won't need to define a comparator because `std::pair` overloads the operator `<` to sort by first element first then second element. 
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4610244/2030653) for an example.

Comment: *"`std::pair is that you won't need to define a comparator"* - that's certainly worthy of mention but only works for increasing order of `.first`...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is struct as the answer by @Gopi. For lexicographical sorting you can use std::tie (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

```
struct vertex
{
    int x;
    int y;
    bool less_x(const struct vertex& b) const { return std::tie(x,y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y); }
    bool less_y(const struct vertex& b) const { return std::tie(y,x) < std::tie(b.y, b.x); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = x*n + y    where, n>x and n>y 

x=c/n 
y=c%n
```

When you need `x` simply `c/n` will give `x` and for `y` use `c%n` gives y.

**Note: Works for positive coordinates only**