# Comparator for sort, specialization

Tags: c++, templates

In a template function a std::vector shall get sorted. T can be a simple type or a std::pair e.g.,

```
std::vector<double> or 
std::vector<std::pair<int,Something> >
```

When T is a pair then only the first element shall be compared. How can I implement the comparator for the two cases?

I have tried:

```
template<typename T>
inline bool smaller(const T& a,const T& b)
{
    return a<b;
}

template<typename T,typename S>
inline bool smaller(
    const std::pair<T,S>& a,
    const std::pair<T,S>& b
    )
{
    return a.first<b.first;
}

template<typename T> inline void function(std::vector<T >& vVec)
{
...bla...
sort(vVec.begin(),vVec.end(),smaller<T>);
...bla...
}
```

but it does not work this way. I have also tried specialization but I do not find the right syntax to specialize the smaller() function.

Comment: Did you try `sort(vVec)` simply?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610232/sorting-a-stdvectorstdpairstdstring-bool-by-the-string

Comment: @Damien, sort(vVec.begin(),vVec.end()) would also compare the second element of the pair. This is not necessary in the application and it would require an operator< for the second element.

Comment: The fact that it is not necessary does not mean that it would be a problem, at the condition of course that the operator `<` is defined for the second element as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just wrap it in a lambda:

```
std::sort(vVec.begin(),vVec.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return smaller(a, b); });
```

Answer (score 3):

One easy work around is to make both of your `smaller` functions `opeator()`'s of a `smaller` struct.  Using

```
struct smaller
{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& a,const T& b)
    {
        return a < b;
    }

    template<typename T, typename S>
    bool operator() (const std::pair<T, S>& a, const std::pair<T, S>& b)
    {
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
};
```

allows you to just pass a `smaller` to `sort` like

```
template<typename T> inline void function(std::vector<T >& vVec)
{
    sort(vVec.begin(),vVec.end(),smaller{});
}
```

and in `sort` overload resolution will kick in on the two `operator()` smaller has and for any `std::vector<std::pair>`, the `std::pair` overload will be called.

Comment: I can accept only one answer as solution and I have chosen the shorter lambda answer below. Your answer would also solve it, thank you very much.

Comment: @Raffi No worries.  Glad to help.